# How to completely overwrite a git branch with another?

Tags: git, merge, overwrite

I have 2 branches

1. `master`
2. `feature`

I would like to completely blow-away the contents of master and replace them with feature branch. **The expected result is, when I run a `diff` over the two branches after the operation, it should not return anything.**

I have searched for many hours now and all the pointers still leave the diff output non-empty.
It is possible that the question has been asked before, but believe me I have tried searching before bothering the community. Please point it out to me if it's a duplicate.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: `git checkout feature && git branch -D master && git checkout -b master && git push origin master --force`

Comment: Thanks! What does that do to the history associated with the **original**  `master` branch?

Comment: It'll wipe it out entirely, but that's what you mean by "blow away the contents of master" right?

Comment: @RobbieAverill Looks like I have everything I need, including history. Thanks! If you would be so kind to add your original comment as an answer it will help those after me.

Comment: glad you got it sorted, but there are probably plenty of answers in the question this one is a duplicate of that you could pass upvotes on to